# useState value is null when callback is done in external component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, callback

I am creating a number of buttons for multiple web pages and created a component file call ToolButtons to do all the work.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const defaultStyling = {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: '10px',
    marginRight: '10px',
    textTransform: 'none'
}

/**
 * This function loops through the button list and generates the button section of the page.
 *
 * @param props tools - Json array of buttons, title - Title for the button group, optional
 * @returns {JSX.Element}
 * @constructor
 */
function ToolButtons(props) {
    return (
        <Card variant='outlined' square>
            <CardContent sx={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: 'column',
                height: '100%',
                padding: 1
            }}>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant='h4' align='center'>{props.title}</Typography>
                <Box sx ={{
                    flex: 1,
                    display: "flex",
                    padding: 2,
                }}>
                    {
                        props.tools.buttons.map(val => (
                            <Button key={val.name}
                                    sx={{...defaultStyling}}
                                    variant='contained'
                                    endIcon={<SendIcon />}
                                    onClick={val.clickHandler}
                                    >{val.text}</Button>
                        ))
                    }
                </Box>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    );
}
export default ToolButtons;
```

This js has the overhead for buttons

```
export const WP_BUTTONS = {
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Clear Scratch Files',
            name: 'clear',
            clickHandler: null
        },
        {
            text: 'Reload BaseLine',
            name: 'rb',
            clickHandler: null
        },
        {
            text: 'Submit',
            name: 'submit',
            clickHandler: null
        },
        {
            text: 'Restart Remote Tower',
            name: 'reboot',
            clickHandler: null
        },
        {
            text: 'Deploy Files',
            name: 'deploy',
            clickHandler: null
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the fuller version of location.js with the fix to the callbacks.  The data variable is set via the useEffect from the backend.  The TextFields all have values after data is set.  If I edit the a field, I can see in debug that the data variable is set, for example:

```
"cameras":[{"file":"cameraConfiguration.xml","id":"panoramaCamera_Visual","baseDeviation":{"azimuth":"140","elevation":"51"},"planeDeviation":{"azimuth":"10.0","elevation":"20.0"}}, {"file":"arcotronAdapterConfiguration.xml","id":"arcotronPtz_LC","baseDeviation":{"azimuth":"23.2","elevation":"44.0"}},
{"file":"common","id":"geolocation","geolocation":{"latitude":"49.174612","longitude":"-86.813558","altitude":"135.0"}}]
```

But if I press any button, the callback function show data is null when using ToolButtons.js.  If I declared the buttons in the location function the data is still set.  So it somehow the callback is not sharing the locationTool memory.  Any ideas why?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Box from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import { Restore } from '@mui/icons-material';
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
import ValidateLocationFields from "./ValidateLocationFields";
import Alerts from '../Alerts';
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";
import ToolButtons from "../ToolButtons";
import {WP_BUTTONS} from "./Constants";

const TWO_COLUMNS = 6;       // Take up 6 of 12 slots for 2 columns
const THREE_COLUMNS = 4;     // Take up 4 of 12 slots for 3 columns

const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;
const SERVLET_NAME = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVLET_NAME;

function LocationTool() {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [dataOrg, setDataOrg] = useState(cloneDeep(null));

    // Holds the status for all the command buttons of the page.
    const [buttons, setButtons] = useState(null);
    const initializeButtons = useRef(false);   // only setup activities.buttons callback 1 time

    // These variables are used to populate the Alert.  The open variable change will cause a redrawing of the page.
    const [alertOpen, setAlertOpen] = useState(false);
    const alertTitle = useRef(null);
    const alertMessage = useRef(null);
    const alertSeverity = useRef("info");

    const url_IR  = API_ENDPOINT + "/" + SERVLET_NAME + "/mcd/location";
    const url_CSF = API_ENDPOINT + "/" + SERVLET_NAME + "/mcd/location/clearScratchFiles";
    const url_W   = API_ENDPOINT + "/" + SERVLET_NAME + "/mcd/location/write";
    const url_RBL = API_ENDPOINT + "/" + SERVLET_NAME + "/mcd/location/readBL";
    const url_RS  = API_ENDPOINT + "/" + SERVLET_NAME + "/mcd/location/rebootServices";
    const url_DS  = API_ENDPOINT + "/" + SERVLET_NAME + "/mcd/location/deployServices";

    const CSF_WFR= useRef(false);
    const W_WFS = useRef(false);
    const RBL_WFR = useRef(false);
    const RS_WFR = useRef(false);
    const DS_WFR = useRef(false);

    const initializeAlert = (title, response) => {
        if (response[0] && response[1]["status"]["code"] === 0) {
            alertTitle.current = "Success";
            alertMessage.current = response[1]["status"]["message"];
            alertSeverity.current = "success";
        } else {
            alertTitle.current = title;
            alertMessage.current = response[1]["status"]["message"];
            alertSeverity.current = "error";
        }
        setAlertOpen(true);
    }

    const closeAlert= () => {
        setAlertOpen(false);
    };

    const postFetchCameras = async (url) => {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(url, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
            });
            let message = await response.json();

            if (message["status"]["code"] === 0) {
                setData(message.data);  /* save the json list */
                const items = cloneDeep(message.data);
                setDataOrg(items);  /* save the json list for restore */
            }

            return [true, message];
        } catch (error)  {
            console.log(error);
            let message = {"status": {"code":1, "message": error.message}};
            return [false, message];
        }
    };

    const handleReloadBL = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!RBL_WFR.current) {
            RBL_WFR.current = true;
            postFetchCameras(url_RBL).then(response => {
                initializeAlert("Error Reading Baseline Location Files", response);
                RBL_WFR.current = false;
            });
        }
    }

    const postHandleSubmit = async (jsonObj) => {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(url_W, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                },
            });
            let message = await response.json();
            return [true, message];
        } catch (error)  {
            console.log(error);
            let message = {"status": {"code":1, "message": error.message}};
            return [false, message];
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        let errorMsg = ValidateLocationFields(data);

        // Did all fields pass validation check?
        if (errorMsg.length === 0) {
            if (!W_WFS.current) {
                W_WFS.current = true;
                postHandleSubmit(data).then(response => {
                    initializeAlert("Error Updating Location Fields", response);
                    W_WFS.current = false;
                });
            }
        } else {
            alertTitle.current = "Invalid fields found";
            alertMessage.current = "Please fix the following fields and submit again.\n\n".concat(errorMsg);
            alertSeverity.current = "error";
            setAlertOpen(true);
        }
    }

    const postCommandResponse = async (url) => {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(url, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
            });
            let message = await response.json();
            return [true, message];
        } catch (error)  {
            console.log(error);
            let message = {"status": {"code":1, "message": error.message}};
            return [false, message];
        }
    };

    const handleClearFiles = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!CSF_WFR.current) {
            CSF_WFR.current = true;
            postCommandResponse(url_CSF).then(response => {
                initializeAlert("Error Clearing Location Scratch Files", response);
                CSF_WFR.current = false;
            });
        }
    }

    const handleRestart = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!RS_WFR.current) {
            RS_WFR.current = true;
            postCommandResponse(url_RS).then(response => {
                initializeAlert("Error Rebooting System", response);
                RS_WFR.current = false;
            });
        }
    }

    const handleDeploy = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log("data; " + JSON.stringify(data));
        if (!DS_WFR.current) {
            DS_WFR.current = true;
            postCommandResponse(url_DS).then(response => {
                initializeAlert("Error Deploying Location Files", response);
                DS_WFR.current = false;
            });
        }
    }

    const handleRestore = (groupTag, myTag, j) => {
        // get the current data and copy it to the replacement json object
        const items = {...data};

        // Example of object pair that needs to be reset using dataOrg
        // items.cameras[j].geolocation.altitude = dataOrg.cameras[j].geolocation.altitude

        items.cameras[j][groupTag][myTag] = dataOrg.cameras[j][groupTag][myTag];

        // now replace the old data object with the new object so the change its saved.
        setData(items);
    };

    const handleChange = (groupTag, myTag, j, e) => {
        let re = new RegExp(''
            + /^-$|/.source                                 // dash only
            + /^-?\d+$|/.source                             // dash optional, n, nn
            + /^-?\d+\.$|/.source                           // dash optional, n., nn.
            + /^-?\d+\.\d+$|/.source                        // dash optional, n.n, nn.nn
            + /^-?[1-9]\d*[Ee]$|/.source                    // dash optional, starts with nonzero nEe, nneE
            + /^-?[1-9]\d*\.\d+[Ee]$|/.source               // dash optional, starts with nonzero n.neE, nn.nneE
            + /^-?[1-9]\d*\.\d+[Ee][-+]$|/.source           // dash optional, starts with nonzero n.neE-+, nn.nneE-+
            + /^-?[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?[Ee][-+]?\d+$/.source   // dash optional, starts with nonzero n.neE-+n, nn.nneE-+nn
        );

        if (e.target.value === '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
            const items = {...data};

            // Example of object pair that needs to be updated
            // items.cameras[j].geolocation.altitude

            items.cameras[j][groupTag][myTag] = e.target.value;

            setData(items);
        }
    }

    function CameraConfiguration(index) {
        return (
            <>
            </>
        );
    }

    function ArcotronAdapterConfiguration(index) {    
        return (
            <>
                <br />
                <Stack direction="row" sx={{my: 4}} alignItems="center" divider={<Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />} spacing={2}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" align="left" gutterBottom>
                        File:  {data.cameras[index].file}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h6" align="left" gutterBottom>
                        Id: {data.cameras[index].id}
                    </Typography>
                </Stack>

                <Typography variant="h6" align="left" gutterBottom>
                    Tag:  baseDeviation
                </Typography>

                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    <Grid item xs={THREE_COLUMNS} sm={TWO_COLUMNS} md={TWO_COLUMNS}>
                        <TextField
                            id={"aplcbda"+index}
                            label="azimuth (degrees 360)"
                            variant="outlined"
                            value={data.cameras[index].baseDeviation.azimuth}
                            onChange={(e) => handleChange("baseDeviation", "azimuth", index, e)}
                            InputProps={{
                                endAdornment: (
                                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                                        <IconButton
                                            color="primary"
                                            size="large"
                                            sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "green" } }}
                                            onClick={() => handleRestore("baseDeviation", "azimuth", index)}
                                            edge="end"
                                        >
                                            <Restore />
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </InputAdornment>
                                )
                            }}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={THREE_COLUMNS} sm={TWO_COLUMNS} md={TWO_COLUMNS}>
                        <TextField
                            id={"aplcbde"+index}
                            label="elevation (+-degrees 90)"
                            variant="outlined"
                            value={data.cameras[index].baseDeviation.elevation}
                            onChange={(e) => handleChange("baseDeviation", "elevation", index, e)}
                            InputProps={{
                                endAdornment: (
                                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                                        <IconButton
                                            color="primary"
                                            size="large"
                                            sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "green" } }}
                                            onClick={() => handleRestore("baseDeviation", "elevation", index)}
                                            edge="end"
                                        >
                                            <Restore />
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </InputAdornment>
                                )
                            }}
                        />
                   </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <br />
            </>
        );
    }

    function Geolocation(index) {    
        return (
            <>
                <br />
                <Stack direction="row" sx={{my: 4}} alignItems="center" divider={<Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />} spacing={2}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" align="left" gutterBottom>
                        File:  {data.cameras[index].file}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h6" align="left" gutterBottom>
                        Tag:  geolocation
                    </Typography>
                </Stack>

                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    <Grid item xs={THREE_COLUMNS} sm={THREE_COLUMNS} md={THREE_COLUMNS}>
                        <TextField
                            id={"geolat"+index}
                            label="latitude (+-degrees 90)"
                            variant="outlined"
                            value={data.cameras[index].geolocation.latitude}
                            onChange={(e) => handleChange("geolocation", "latitude", index, e)}
                            InputProps={{
                                endAdornment: (
                                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                                        <IconButton
                                            color="primary"
                                            size="large"
                                            sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "green" } }}
                                            onClick={() => handleRestore("geolocation", "latitude", index)}
                                            edge="end"
                                        >
                                            <Restore />
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </InputAdornment>
                                )
                            }}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={THREE_COLUMNS} sm={THREE_COLUMNS} md={THREE_COLUMNS}>
                        <TextField
                            id={"geolon"+index}
                            label="longitude (+-degrees 180)"
                            variant="outlined"
                            value={data.cameras[index].geolocation.longitude}
                            onChange={(e) => handleChange("geolocation", "longitude", index, e)}
                            InputProps={{
                                endAdornment: (
                                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                                        <IconButton
                                            color="primary"
                                            size="large"
                                            sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "green" } }}
                                            onClick={() => handleRestore("geolocation", "longitude", index)}
                                            edge="end"
                                        >
                                            <Restore />
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </InputAdornment>
                                )
                            }}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={THREE_COLUMNS} sm={THREE_COLUMNS} md={THREE_COLUMNS}>
                        <TextField
                            id={"geoalt"+index}
                            label="altitude (double) Meters"
                            variant="outlined"
                            value={data.cameras[index].geolocation.altitude}
                            onChange={(e) => handleChange("geolocation", "altitude", index, e)}
                            InputProps={{
                                endAdornment: (
                                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                                        <IconButton
                                            color="primary"
                                            size="large"
                                            sx={{ "&:hover": { color: "green" } }}
                                            onClick={() => handleRestore("geolocation", "altitude", index)}
                                            edge="end"
                                        >
                                            <Restore />
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </InputAdornment>
                                )
                            }}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <br />
            </>
        );
    }

    const buttonStates = {
        clear: handleClearFiles,
        rb: handleReloadBL,
        submit: handleSubmit,
        reboot: handleRestart,
        deploy: handleDeploy,
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // We only want to initialize this one like a constructor, not everytime the page is rendered
        if (!initializeButtons.current) {
            setButtons({
                ...WP_BUTTONS,
                buttons: WP_BUTTONS.buttons.map((button) => ({
                    ...button,
                    clickHandler: buttonStates[button.name],
                })),
            });
            initializeButtons.current = true;

            postFetchCameras(url_IR).then(response => {
                if (!response[0]) {
                    initializeAlert("Error Reading Configuration Files", response);
                }
            });
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    /**
     Create the location html fields for the page.
     */
    return buttons && data ? (
        <Box sx={{ margin: 2 }}>
            <Typography variant="h2" align="center" sx={{mb: 1}} gutterBottom>
                Geolocation of Remote Tower
            </Typography>
            {
                data && data.cameras.map((item, index) => {
                    if (item.file === "cameraConfiguration.xml") {
                        return (
                            CameraConfiguration(index)
                        )
                    } else if (item.file === "arcotronAdapterConfiguration.xml") {
                        return (
                            ArcotronAdapterConfiguration(index)
                        )
                    } else if (item.file === "common") {
                        return (
                            Geolocation(index)
                        )
                    }
                    return("")
                })
            }

            <ToolButtons tools={buttons} title=''/>

            <Alerts open={alertOpen} severity={alertSeverity.current} onClose={closeAlert}
                    title={alertTitle.current} message={alertMessage.current}/>
        </Box>
    ) : null;
}

export default LocationTool;
```

Comment: Can you show a little bit from buttons prop structure and the clickhandlers that you pass down to ToolButtons component?

Comment: add more code to show what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

So Initially MCD_STATE has 3 buttons, all of them are null. You are trying to mutate them but you did not update your state "activities".

I would create a copy of activities state, modify the values like clickHandler of a button, then update MCD_STATE. Also, activities state can be null initially, then you don't need the ref you created. You only render ToolButtons if activities not null. After you updated your activities state with useEffect, it will render ToolButtons component.

**Please note that I have not tried and there may be an error in my code!**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!initializeActivities.current) {
    const activityButtons = MCD_STATE.buttons.map((button) => {
      let clickHandler = "";
      if (button.name === "reboot") {
        clickHandler = "handleRestart";
      } else if (button.name === "deploy") {
        clickHandler = "handleDeploy";
      } else if (button.name === "rpm") {
        clickHandler = "handleCreateRpm";
      } else {
        console.error("Wrong tool option: " + button.name);
      }
      return {
        ...button,
        clickHandler,
      };
    });
    const newActivities = {
      ...MCD_STATE,
      buttons: activityButtons,
    };
    setActivities(newActivities);
    initializeActivities.current = true;
  }
}, []);
```

if you are familiar with nested ternary operator then a shorter version:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!initializeActivities.current) {
    const activityButtons = MCD_STATE.buttons.map((button) => ({
      ...button,
      clickHandler:
        button.name === "reboot"
          ? "handleRestart"
          : button.name === "deploy"
          ? "handleDeploy"
          : button.name === "rpm"
          ? "handleCreateRpm"
          : `tool option not found ${button.name}`,
    }));
    setActivities({
      ...MCD_STATE,
      buttons: activityButtons,
    });
    initializeActivities.current = true;
  }
}, []);
```

With switch-case:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!initializeActivities.current) {
    const activityButtons = MCD_STATE.buttons.map((button) => {
      let clickHandler = "";

      switch(button.name) {
        case "reboot":
          clickHandler = "handleRestart";
          break;
        case "deploy":
          clickHandler = "handleDeploy";
          break;
        case "rpm":
          clickHandler = "handleCreateRpm";
          break;
        default:
          clickHandler = `tool option not found ${button.name}`;
      }

      return {
        ...button,
        clickHandler,
      };
    });

    setActivities({
      ...MCD_STATE,
      buttons: activityButtons,
    });

    initializeActivities.current = true;
  }
}, []);
```

Shortest:

```js
const buttonStates = {
  reboot: "handleRestart",
  deploy: "handleDeploy",
  rpm: "handleCreateRpm",
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (!initializeActivities.current) {
    setActivities({
      ...MCD_STATE,
      buttons: MCD_STATE.buttons.map((button) => ({
        ...button,
        clickHandler: buttonStates[button.name],
      })),
    });
    initializeActivities.current = true;
  }
}, []);
```

Finally your LocationTool component:

```js
const cardStyles = {
  width: "86%",
  marginLeft: "7%",
  padding: 1,
  border: "none",
  boxShadow: "none",
};

function LocationTool() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [dataOrg, setDataOrg] = useState(cloneDeep(null));
  const [activities, setActivities] = useState(null);

  const buttonStates = {
    reboot: "handleRestart",
    deploy: "handleDeploy",
    rpm: "handleCreateRpm",
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setActivities({
      ...MCD_STATE,
      buttons: MCD_STATE.buttons.map((button) => ({
        ...button,
        clickHandler: buttonStates[button.name],
      })),
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    let errorMsg = ValidateLocationFields(data);
  };

  return activities ? (
    <Card sx={cardStyles} square>
      <CardContent>
        <ActivitiesSection
          state={activities}
          title="Maintenance and Configuration Dashboard"
        />
        <ToolButtons tools={activities} title="System Tools" />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  ) : null;
}
```

Comment: I changed the code and the buttons are now calling the callbacks ok. 
 The only problems with your code change was the buttonStates block and useEffect had to be after the functions were all declared and the double quotes were making the functions into string names so I delete them.  But the  useState() variables are still null in the callbacks, but are set in the non-callback functions.   Again, it appears that the callback memory is somehow not part to the locationTool memory.   Any idea what is going on with useState?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean about "useState() variables are still null in the callbacks, but are set in the non-callback functions".  It would be nice if you could provide a codesandbox, a small demo so I could understand the purpose of your application.
useState is a local state that is belongs to your component. It could be that a re-render causing your state refresh. You call the callback, some side effect happens in it, your component re-render and your state will be null as it is initially.

Comment: Ok, I pasted in the full js file, I had to cut out camera layout to fit.  If I change values I see data is set in the debugger and the values are in their textfields.  But if I enter a callback, all the useEffect values are null or default values.   This does not happen if I do the buttons inside locationTools directly.